# Why the wave on a battery is neither square nor sine?

Tags: batteries, oscilloscope, waveform

I’m measuring the electrical wave on a 1.5 V battery - why is the wave this particular shape? Isn’t it supposed to be sine or square? Thanks!

[image: screenshot from oscilloscope]

[image: setup]

Comment: What is the context? A schematic diagram would help enormously.

Comment: No, a battery should normally just be a flat line. DC voltage at 1.5V. No waves involved. Where are you connecting the scope probe ground connection?

Comment: @Justin to the battery minus pole.

Comment: why would there be a wave at all? It is DC source. The only "wave" would be the measurement noise.

Comment: Can you add a full picture of your measurement setup? You're just measuring a battery by itself, right?

Comment: You are not measuring the battery at all, you are measuring noise coupled in, probably from the power line.  Like any voltmeter, a scope needs two connections to the circuit under test, and for a battery the mains won't even provide a roundabout one.  Make sure both the probe and it's ground are completing their parts of the circuit.

Comment: If that 5mS at the bottom means 5mS per div, then the period is 20mS, frequency is 50Hz, spot on for power line noise, not the 70Hz shown on the scope!

Comment: @Justin yes, i'm just attaching the red cable to the battery's plus

Comment: @ChrisStratton so what would be the proper way to check the signal? should I attach the red cable to minus and the black one to plus or to the ground? thanks!

Comment: @DmitryParanyushkin red to plus, black to minus.

Comment: Could be any of misuse, a broken test lead, a bad toy scope or a noisy power supply.  Given you are not seeing the battery cell's DC contribution at all misuse or a broken leas are the first and cheapest suspects.

Comment: It looks like mains noise. It usually looks like this (distorted sine wave). Are you running oscilloscope from battery or power adapter? If from power adapter, earthing the -ve will reduce or eliminate the noise.

Comment: Nice they minused me for asking a question that reveals a non-professional in me, so I can't ask questions anymore on this site. Great.

Comment: @Indraneel  — maybe you want to post your response as the answer as it helped me resolve the issue... Thanks!

Comment: @Dmitry Paranyushkin don't be offended by a few minuses.  I didn't add one, but people aren't judging you on any missing education.  They will, however, demand your effort.  The obvious problems with this question are the lack of information and not showing both connections in the bottom picture(although it's good to include pictures and your lighting and focus are good).  If you tune up a question, some downvotes will disappear.  If you ended up providing any additional information in the comments, always be sure to add it to the question body.

Comment: I think this is a decent question now. Doesn't deserve all the downvotes and I don't think it should be closed just yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These battery operated oscilloscopes do not have much filtering for the supply voltage. Thus any noise in the supply shows up in the output. Even a mains transformer based linear regulated supply (e.g. 9V step down transformer and LM317) will pass enough mains signal for oscilloscope output to be a problem. The +ve output of the supply is 9V with respect to the -ve wire (0 V), but the common mode mains signal is not rejected.

A simple solution is to earth (earth pin in mains socket) the power supply output ground (i.e. 0V or -ve output terminal of power supply). Additionally, one can also earth the iron core of the mains transformer (if any). This brings the ground reference of the oscilloscope to a stable voltage. The +ve supply also stabilizes due to the linear regulator.

During use, one does have to remember that the oscilloscope is now earthed, and no more floating. This is no different than any other mains operated bench oscilloscope. The device under test thus needs to be floating (more so since this is a single channel scope, so no math functions for differential measurement).

Your wave shows a 50 Hz sine wave, with additional distortion at the peaks. This distortion is likely due to input capacitors used for the DC-DC switching supply (e.g. MC34063 based) which generates the -ve voltage (-9V or -5V) for the op amps. Depending on the location of the capacitors and inductor on the PCB, some of the switching noise may also end up in the output of the oscilloscope. Marginally better performance may be obtained by modifying or replacing the -ve voltage generator (e.g. moving the switcher away to a different PCB, or isolating the switcher ground, or using another battery).

PS: glad your problem got resolved!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you may have activated the storage function of the oscilloscope before you connected the probes to the battery.  If that is the case, then the scope will have grabbed a frame of mains noise and displayed it prior to connecting the battery.

Turn off the storage mode and see if it then displays a flat line when connected to the battery.